# Site has split me into two users?

Tags: support, status-completed

I've noticed that when I visit, the site will list me as user johnnyBrandom (unregistered) or johnnyBrandom (registered) depending on which browser I use. Also, it is tracking my questions/answers and reputation separately depending on which user it thinks I am: johnnyBrandom-registered or johnnyBrandom-unregistered.

Is there some way to fix this? I think the first two answers I posted I may not have been registered but since then I have registered using the same username but I noticed that my user id's are different. Is there anyway to consolidate/merge into the same user without losing the reputation points?

Thanks.

edit:

https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/731/johnnybrandom
https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/771/johnnybrandom

Comment: I can merge easily, its a matter of tracking the unreg'd account as a general search does not pull it up.  Can you edit the question with links to both accounts?

Answer (score 1):

## Done and done